# Strength of claims about extensions of partial preorders and orders to linear ones

Tags: axiom-of-choice, posets, reverse-math

Consider these two axioms:

1. Every partial order extends to a linear order.
2. Every partial preorder (reflexive and transitive relation) extends to a linear preorder while preserving strict orderings: i.e., whenever $x<y$ (namely: $x\lesssim y$ but not $y\lesssim x$) holds in the original order, it holds in the extended order.

**Question:** Does 2 imply 1 in ZF?

**Notes:**

A. In ZF, Boolean Prime Ideal implies 1 (but not conversely if ZF is consistent), and 1 implies 2 (take the quotient of the preordered set under $\sim$, where $x\sim y$ iff $x\lesssim y$ and $y\lesssim x$, and apply 1).

B. Also, 2+(every set has a linear order) implies 1.  (Use 2 to extend the partial order $\le$ to a total preorder $\lesssim$ preserving strict orderings.  We now need to turn $\lesssim$ into a linear order.  To do that, we just need to linearly order within each equivalence class under $\sim$.  Do that by taking a linear order on the whole set and using that to induce the order in each equivalence class---though not between them.)

C. Claim 2 implies Banach-Tarski and thus the existence of nonmeasurable sets (Pawlikowski's proof of Banach-Tarski from Hahn-Banach [can be adapted](http://alexanderpruss.blogspot.com/2013/12/ordering-sets-and-banach-tarski-paradox.html)), and hence 2 is not provable in ZF (if ZF is consistent).

Comment: I have to check more carefully, but I am pretty sure that D is badly argued: it's not clear that $\preceq$ as I defined it is transitive.