# Reverse-mathematical strength of Banach-Tarski

Tags: lo.logic, measure-theory, axiom-of-choice, reverse-math, banach-tarski

What is the reverse mathematical strength of the Banach-Tarski paradox?

---

The usual proof of Banach-Tarski should carry out in $\mathrm{ZF}+\mathrm{AC}_\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is the supremum of the sizes of partitions of $\mathbb R$, and $\mathrm{AC}_\kappa$ is choice for families of sets of size $\kappa$. However I am mainly focusing on replacing $\textrm{ZF}$ here with a weaker theory.

All machinery appearing in the proof seems to have low rank in the [von Neumann hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe), so the axiom of powerset does not seem to have to be iterated many times. (In contrast it is a result of Friedman that Borel determinacy requires $\omega_1$-fold iteration of powerset applies to $\mathbb N$ in order to prove, although its statement only refers to sets of low rank. Yet all machinery used in proving Banach-Tarski seems to have low rank.) For example, if $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is identified with the reals, the unit ball will be a subset of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(N))$, a finite set of pieces of the unit ball will be codable as a member of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal N))$ using a coding function $[\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal N))]^{<\aleph_0}\to \mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal N))$ (where $[\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal N))]^{<\aleph_0}$ is the set of finite subsets of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal N))$), and a quotient of the unit ball will be identified with $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb N)))$.

---

Some results are known about theories being sufficient or not sufficient to prove Banach-Tarski, although most are about choice rather than replacing the $\mathrm{ZF}$ part of the theory:

- It is known that the Hahn-Banach theorem implies the Banach-Tarski paradox. (Pawlikowski, "[The Hahn-Banach theorem implies the Banach-Tarski Paradox](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm138/fm13813.pdf)", 1989), proven with base theory $\mathrm{ZF}$.
- It is known that Banach-Tarski is implied by the statement "every partial preorder extends to a linear preorder that preserves strict order" ([MO question #150945](https://mathoverflow.net/q/150945)), but this is proven with base theory $\mathrm{ZF}$.
- Banach-Tarski is number HR 309 in Howard and Rubin's book *Consequences of the Axiom of Choice*. There is an MO question "[Equivalence of the Banach–Tarski paradox](https://mathoverflow.net/q/234372)" relevant to this result.
- Banach-Tarski is known to not be provable in $\mathrm{ZF}+\mathrm{DC}$ if it is consistent, where $\mathrm{DC}$ is the axiom of dependent choice. (Corollary 13.3 of Wagon, *The Banach-Tarski Paradox*, 1993)

Comment: It's not too clear what you are asking.  Are you asking whether Banach-Tarski reverses to some other standard axiom/theorem over some system weaker than ZF?  Or are you asking what the minimal version of Choice is that would be needed to prove Banach-Tarski?

Comment: @MikhailKatz When originally posting I may have had too broad of a question in mind, with the intended goal being to optimize on "two fronts" (both weakening the base theory and weakening the choice assumption), rather than a reversal to a standard theorem. This may be too ambitious, so I will refocus and rephrase the post. The question of weakening the necessary choice assumption seems to already be better-documented, so I will ask about weakening the base theory.

Comment: C7X, thanks for the clarification.  You may want to elaborate a bit on the interesting issue concerning ZF+DC.  Here as you know Solovay is not sufficient because of the IC hypothesis, but an additive total measure can be constructed anyway.